# force:recordEdit UI not working properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, force-recordedit

I am playing with force:recordEdit and it's looks like there is some issue in UI. Here i have attached the code and UI screenshot. In this example i have used hard coded id of contact record for testing purpose. is there any work around to make it proper?

i have used `<force:recordEdit recordId="003j000000FLimQAAT"/>` this in my component,

App

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:TestLTPage/>
</aura:application>
```

Cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1"  class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" title="Close">
                        <div aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large">
                            <img src="/resource/SLDS/assets/icons/action/close_60.png" style="width:24px !important;"/>
                        </div>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>

                    <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Edit Contact</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <div>
                       <force:recordEdit recordId="003j000000FLimQAAT"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
</aura:component>
```

UI Output.
[image]

**My Experience:** I think I have find out it's work perfect in One.app container.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to show the default edit page then you can use the following

`<ui:outputURL value="{!'/'+account.Id+'/e?retURL=%2Fa'+account.Id}" label="Edit" aura:id="detailContURL" target=""/>`

This one open as a modal with default edit functionality.

Please let me know if it's work